# Pass selected date values from datepicker to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, datepicker

I found similar questions on here but most of the solutions don't work for me. I have a form with a datepicker and I want to pass the selected date to my php file but it doesn't seem to work.

My html is something like this:

```
<form name="myForm" action="createevent.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get"> 
<p>Date<input type="text" id="mydate" /></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.extend($.datepicker.regional[""]));
$("#mydate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var dateAsString = dateText; 
    alert (dateAsString); //this prints out the right value.
    alert (mydate.value); //this value is the same as dateText
    }
});
```

createevent.php

```
function CreateEvent()
{
    if(isset($_GET['submit']))
    {
        $mydate=$_GET['mydate'];
        echo $mydate;
    }
    }
```

When I alert (mydate.value), it gives the correct value. But when I echo $mydate in my php file, it doesn't show anything. Any help is appreciated!

Update:

Thank you guys! I made a silly mistake. Adding "name" attribute works. I have a follow up question. I have a timepicker as well and it returns something like 01:21. My date returns something like 01/01/2013. Is there a way to combine these two and make it a datetime type so I can add to my database? Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not sure but you should add a `name` attribute to your input in order to get it by `$_GET`. Try adding `name="mydate"` to your input

Comment: oops, sorry @Antonio Laguna, didn't saw your comment, seems I got a cached copy when you comment on it

Comment: My bad Simon! I should have replied instead of commenting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems you're doing nothing with the date after the `onSelect` has fired, the only thing wrong I see is that your input is lacking the name attribute, and it won't be visible in the `$_GET` superglobal

Change your input to something like:

```
<input type="text" id="mydate" name="mydate"/>
```

And it should work.

If you plan to store your date and time in a MySQL database, you could do something like this. First in your form:

```
<form name="myForm" action="createevent.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get"> 
<p>Date<input type="text" id="mydate" name="mydate"/></p>
<p>Time<input type="text" id="mytime" name="mytime"/></p>
<input type="hidden" id="mydatetime" name="mydatetime"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then, in your `validateForm()` function, I would add something like this:

```
var date = $('#mydate').val(),
    time = $('#mytime').val();

var datetime = [date.replace('/','-'),time].join(' '); // 01-01-2013 01:21
$('#mydatetime').val(datetime);
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please check my follow-up question?

Comment: Check the updated answer please, but next time ask in another question as this is totally different.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't tried but I'm wondering maybe it's just your control got "name" missing, try change it as following:

```
<input type="text" id="mydate" name="mydate"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Made change in input box

```
<input type="text" id="mydate" />
```

TO :

```
<input type="text" id="mydate" name="mydate"/>
```

When you will submit form it will submit name value of textbox mydate and you can get it by `$_GET["mydate"]`

Comment: @Dao Lam , means you post time and date separately and want to store in database combined ?

Comment: Correct. because in my database, the value is type datetime.

Comment: @Dao Lam , as i know you must have to set your date and time in this format <code>2012-06-06 07:11:50</code>, because type you select datetime. u used datepicker so you can change date format in library.